# c++ const struct initialization

Tags: c++, struct, constants

I need to initialize this variable: `const WAVEFORMATEX *pFormat` with valid values for the struct's fields.

First I tried modifying after declaration: `(*pFormat).wFormatTag = 0;` then soon found that the const modifier disallows such action. Then I tried variations of inline initialization

```
new WAVEFORMATEX() { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; //or 
WAVEFORMATEX { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

The first throws an 'expecting a ;' error and the second initialization expression does not return the correct type. Could someone help? There is a function call that I am using later that MUST have a parameter of type const WAVEFORMATEX *.

Here's the struct docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390970(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: if the function takes a `const WAVEFORMATEX *` argument that just means that you have to pass it the address of a `WAVEFORMATEX` structure, and the function guarantees not to change the contents of the structure.

Comment: Why the down-votes? Down-votes without any comments for the reasons why are lame!

Comment: I am not sure of the real problem you are trying to solve. Using `const T* ptr = new T;` is not ideal. You cannot use `delete ptr;` on such a pointer. You'll leak memory.

Comment: Interesting. I think I have a lot more research to do as far as heap memory allocation in c++. I have no idea why I wouldn't be able to delete ptr. I thought I would leak memory if I DIDN'T use delete after the new keyword use.

Comment: @R_Sahu it seems that you can use `delete` on a `const T*`.

Comment: I don't know who down-voted, but read a book on programming in C++ (perhaps *Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++*) and maybe you'll understand the down votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that a function expects a parameter of `const WAVEWHATEVER*` type does not mean you have to declare this struct so that it becomes `const WAVEWHATEVER*` at the same time, just use:

```
 void foo(const WAVEWHATEVER* w) {}

 WAVEWHATEVER w;
 w.FormatTag = 0;
 // [...] and so on
 foo(&w);
```

The function only guarantees it will not change your original `w`'s content.

Comment: Thanks, I'm very new to c++.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
const WAVEFORMATEX * pFormat = new WAVEFORMATEX{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

This will allow you to initialize a `const T*` in one expression. Other methods exist to make your intent more clear or robust in the face of changes, such as creating a factory function, etc.

The difference between this and what you have tried previously is the lack of the `()`. Using the `()` will try to call a default constructor with no parameters and then results in a syntax error when it is immediately followed by an initializer list.

Not using the `new` operator will result in you allocating your memory on the stack instead of the heap and your type is wrong since the result is not a pointer.

Comment: It seems that the other answers show how to use the API you are using in a better way.

Comment: Why do you think the other answer is better? This way is much more concise as far as readability. I just have to remember to delete pFormat from the heap.

Comment: The other answer shows you that perhaps you don't actually want a `const WAVEFORMATEX *`, and that you can achieve your goals without this constraint. It is up to you to decide what will work best in your actual application though.

Comment: My answer addresses a potential misunderstanding of the syntax. The other answer addresses a potential misunderstanding of the API. Both answers may be useful to someone reading this question.

Comment: @gordlonious: 1. this one will not work in pre-C++11 compiler, 2. you are using raw pointer that you have to delete, 3. you are putting constraints on your variable (no more changes), 4. it is unreadable which fields are actually defined in which place, 5. if someone changes the structure definition by adding field inside your code works differently